# How to bring Keynote's back to normal

Tags: macbook-pro, keynote

I started using keynote today and noticed that the colors change. The theme color, the font color and even the pictures i add have a pink/purple-ish color and it's really hard to edit under these conditions. If anyone knows how to bring back the colors to normal I would really appreciate it, thank you

Comment: Use grab to take a picture and upload it somewhere in the comments. I can embed it if you flag for help.

Comment: Does this also happen if you create a new presentation based on the same theme?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried backing and removing your "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork.Keynote.plist file"?  Try closing Keynote, then moving or backing up and deleting that file.  Then start Keynote again. There may be a config in "/Library/Preferences" as well. Kind of a shot in the dark, but the "~/Library" folder is where most user specific preferences are stored.

Comment: Have you tried loading Keynote as a different user to see if the settings persist between different users on the same machine or just your user?